# "Drawing" single vertices obstructed by coordinate axes

Tags: modeling

I cannot "draw" single vertices because that coordinate system Axes (Green, Red) are in my way. How can I draw vertices in straight lines instead?

[image]

Every time I want to draw a path which overlaps with the green and red thing it's not possible to do so. I'm not able to click there.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, do you wan't to remove the green and red lines, add more vertices, or move that vertex somewhere?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. But in general the prefered way to use the 3d manipulator, is to no use them. Ideally you would use the keyboard shortcuts with the 3d manipulator hidden ctrl+space.

Comment: Yah! Thats ok!Its because i want wo draw something but i cant do that in straight lines Thanks! it Works

Answer (score 7):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle the 3d manipulator between visible and hidden. Or you toggle  it by clicking on it.

[image]

---

If you are referring to the fact that once you extrude you no longer see the manipulator that is because after you extrude you automatically go into grab mode, which will hide the manipulator. So if you want to move it along an axis you have two ways of doing this.

**Method 1 (preferred)**

1. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude like you normally would
2. Constrain the extrude to an axis by pressing either: <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>

**Method 2**

1. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude like you normally would
2. Drop the tool, RMB or <kbd>Esc</kbd>
3. Use the 3d manipulator to move it like you are used to

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Your question isn't clear, some edits would be nice...* anyways:

If you're trying to add single vertices, you ***could*** create one by adding and scaling a primitive like a cube, down to 0 (<kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd>), then using <kbd>W</kbd>>*Remove doubles*. The best way to add more however would be to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. **If you want to make a straight line**, use <kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> to confine it to an axis.

Comment: I grow weary of typing this repeatedly especially to the same 3 people, if it isn't clear, wait for clarification before posting whatever you think it is. I really don't understand the rush to answer every new question within 10 seconds of it being posted.